# Can I re-order columns in exporting CSV on Drupal 8 Webform Submissions?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-webform

Currently, there is a results download feature with [webform core module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and we can select the columns to include in exporting CSV file.

[image]

But I couldn't figure it out how can we re-order these columns to show them in exact custom order we require in exporting CSV file.

Is this possible with current features provided or is this achievable using some custom code and Webform Submission Exporter provided?

Any help, direction or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to extend the DelimitedWebformExporter and add the column sorting logic.

Another approach is to use the [Webform View Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views) module and build a completely custom CSV.